# how to replace the existing clone data to new data retrieved

Tags: javascript, mootools

```
var copy = $('sports1').clone(true);
copy.getChildren("span.yearsplayedtext").set('html', yearsplayed);
$('profile-sports-holder').appendChild(copy);
$('profile-holder-sportsadd').hide();
```

Comment: Is `yearsplayed` the new data? and what should it replace? the content of `profile-sports-holder`?

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, i am trying to clone the   <span class="Block-head">Played for : </span><span class="yearsplayedtext"> <?php echo $sports['yearsplayed'];?> years </span>
</p>
<p><span class="Block-head">Grades: </span>
<span><?php if($sports['nineth'] == 1){
       if(($sports['tenth'] == 1)||($sports['eleventh'] == 1)||($sports['twelveth'] == 1)){
 echo '<span class="spacercls">9th,&nbsp;</span>'                            for this code i have to replace the data

Comment: Can you post the HTML after the PHP in the question? ie as it comes to the browser after rendering

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you are doing. As it stands, the question is not clear enough.